# Cairo text-alignment gtkmm 2 -

Tags: c++, cairo, gtkmm, text-alignment

I have an issue concerning text-aligning in gtkmm 2

I cannot find an easy way of aligning the text in relation to the left fram-border, according to the screenshoot.

In some way I solved the problem with some mathematics but its not optimal.

So my question is - is there any easy way to right-align the labels?

[image]